# Android: How to add enum labels to a spinner, not the enum.values()?

Tags: java, android, enums, spinner, google-translate

I am trying to make a spinner list where my users can select a language translations based on enum 'Language' class.

Adding the '`Language.values()`' works, 
but the spinner shows "af" not "AFRIKAANS" 
I want the "AFRIKAANS" name shown in the spinner and `onItemSelected` I want the get the "af" value.

is this possible?

```
public enum Language {
       AUTO_DETECT(""),
       AFRIKAANS("af"),
       ALBANIAN("sq"),
       AMHARIC("am") ....and so no..
```

See hold enum class here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/api/translate/Language.java

```
spinnerLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.translate_spinner_language);
spinnerLanguage.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Language>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Language.values()));
spinnerLanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) 
    {
       Log.i("language", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of overriding `toString()`, change it to different function:

```
public String shortCode() {
  return language;
}
```

This way `toString()` will return `AFRIKAANS` for the `Spinner` display, and you can call `shortCode()` in `onItemSelected()` to get `af`.

Comment: Cool got it to work :) Log.i( Language.fromString(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()).shortCode() );